# HashMap <Key: Student , Value : List<Evals> > Returns reference of Student Not Object of Student

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I have method which returns `Map<AcadStudent, List<AcadStudentEvaluation>>` . I got Student object from Database using by find method of Entity Manager and got Evaluations by query. Then I do this :

```
myMap.put(Student,Evaluations);
```

and when I'm seeing result in console I got reference of Student like this : ge.gov.mia.academy.entities.AcadStudent@74dc9778

Can anybody tell me what is wrong or what is problem ?

Comment: how did you print the result to the console?

Comment: Invoke Method, using by javascript

Comment: That's the default string representation of any java object if you don't override `toString` to produce something more meaningful.

Comment: But I don't use toString method

Comment: yes but you should use `toString()` method and override it in your entity class. otherwise you always get only the jvm intern reference of the object. if you dont want to override `toString()` you have to print out the single attributes.

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is overriding toString() ?

Comment: yes, or print every single attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian Roberts said you haven't override `toString` method to get the string from java object.

Comment: I want to get object not string

Comment: But how should the print method know how to print a whole object?

Comment: so let me understand you want to print all the values of the object Student ?